# iOS Audio unit get current time stamp

Tags: ios, timestamp, audio-streaming

I'm using  audio unit (iOS) to play music from file. How do I get the current time stamp of  the music I m playing?

I found that there is a variable call "inTimeStamp" of type AudioTimeStamp in the playbackCallback function. Is it the right place i look for the current time stamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you are:

```
AudioTimeStamp ts;
UInt32 size = sizeof(ts);

AudioUnitGetProperty(THIS->audioPlayerUnit,
                     kAudioUnitProperty_CurrentPlayTime, 
                     kAudioUnitScope_Global, 
                     0, &ts, &size);

NSLog(@"TS%f", ts.mSampleTime);
```

A better way to get the seconds is to add

```
THIS->currentTime = ts.mSampleTime / THIS.streamFormatDescription.mSampleRate;
```

Comment: I tried using this method to get the current time stamp of an audio file that I trying to play using audio unit, but it returns an empty 'ts' structure. It doesn't change the previous values at all. (Audio playback is working)

Comment: i get -10879, that is, kAudioUnitErr_InvalidProperty as return value

Comment: This method only works for kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer AudioUnit type, since kAudioUnitProperty_CurrentPlayTime is useful only for this unit type.

Answer (score 1):

loretoparisi's answer is not suited for all scenes. If you're using kAudioUnitSubType_AudioFilePlayer, then try his answer; but if you're using other audio unit types such as RemoteIO unit, you need to set a global variable that stores the frame count that the audio unit has rendered, and update the value in every render cycle.

```
player.progress += inNumberFrames/player.canonicalFormat.mSampleRate;
```